# Best index practice on table containing large amount of data

Tags: sql-server, indexing

My question is, if I need a clustered or non-clustered index.
This is my case:

I have a table with appr. 100.000.000 records.
The design is: 
tblLarge:
Col1 varchar(30) not null
Col2 varchar(12) not null
col3 Varchar(30) not null
insertTime datatime

I only do inserts(a lot of inserts. Appr. 15.000.000 a day). Never updates or deletes (I truncate the table now and then)

The only select is: 
select Col1 from tblLarge where Col2 = 'some data' order by insertTime desc
- this select is performed constantly.

Col2 is not unique, but never null.

Questions:
1) What kind of index(s) would be the best to apply to the table in my situation?
Of cause I need an index on Col2. Should it be CLUSTERED or NON-CLUSTERED?
(some guy once told me, that tables always should have a CLUSTERED index, but I'm not sure if this is right)

2) is the NOLOCK hint good or bad practice? (I don't mind if the select reads un-committed data)
select Col1 from tblLarge(NOLOCK) where Col2 = 'some data' order by insertTime desc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no identity column, so a clustered index would require too much disk activity when inserting the new records. You need a non-clustered index on col2, to include the field you wish to return, col1:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblLarge_col2] ON [dbo].[tblLarge]
(
    [col2] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [col1]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```